# CherryPy access restrictions with static files

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy server that dispenses a few static HTML/JS/etc. files to /foosball, plus some JSON through a REST API to /.

```
import cherrypy

config = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
        'server.socket_port': # my port here,
        'tools.json_in.on': True
    },
    '/foosball': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.root': '/var/www/html',
        'tools.staticdir.dir': 'foosball',
        'tools.staticdir.index': 'index.html'
    }
}

@cherrypy.popargs('player_id')
class RESTClient_Player(object):
    # stuff

class RESTClient_Game(object):
    # stuff

class RESTClient:
    players = RESTClient_Player()
    games = RESTClient_Game()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        http_method = getattr(self, cherrypy.request.method)
        return (http_method)()

cherrypy.quickstart(RESTClient(), '/', config)
```

I also want to keep these pages protected by a basic access restriction scheme, so I've been examining [the excellent tutorial CherryPy provides](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions).

Trouble is, the documentation is geared towards authenticating non-static pages, the kind explicitly declared by `def` statements. I tried and failed to adapt this documentation to the files in /foosball, but without success. /foosball always ends up loading without any authentication request.

What can I add to give static files some access restriction ability?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** I got pointed towards auth_tool. With the below config block, I was able to lock up the REST API portion with a login screen, but all static files in /foosball are still openly accessible:

```
def check_login_and_password(login, password):
    cherrypy.log(login)
    cherrypy.log(password)

    return

config = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
        'server.socket_port': # my port here,
        'tools.json_in.on': True,
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.session_auth.on': True,
        'tools.session_auth.check_username_and_password': check_login_and_password
    },
    '/foosball': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.root': '/var/www/html',
        'tools.staticdir.dir': 'foosball',
        'tools.staticdir.index': 'index.html',
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.session_auth.on': True,
        'tools.session_auth.check_username_and_password': check_login_and_password
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [session_auth](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html?highlight=session_auth#cherrypy.lib.cptools.session_auth) tool?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. See the above edit for my experience.

Comment: The files must be coming from the browser cache, try Ctrl + Refresh. I've just tried it and auth tool did work for me, although it was not smart enough to change content type from image to html on login form display. Hopefully it's configurable.

Comment: Previously posted that cache wasn't the culprit (I blasted away a week's worth of browser cache), but when I hit the same URL in Internet Explorer (a browser I never use), I got the correct login page. Very strange. But I suppose I'm where I want to be now, as long as I can figure out how to get users' cache correctly cleared. BTW, @jwalker, if you repost your comment as an answer I'll give you credit.

Comment: For cache control try `expires` tool. Not sure my advice qualifies for an answer, particularly for we don't know yet if it's really feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the "staticdir" in your config, you can create a function in your class that will return static files.  If you do that, you can wrap authentication around your function.

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file
import os

class Hello(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def static(self, page):
        return serve_file(os.path.join(current_dir, 'static', page), content_type='text/html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    cherrypy.quickstart(Hello())
```